# How to set Limit or query Go Language Mysql?

Tags: go

How to Set mysql limit in Go Language? I try it to php it is working but in the Go language, it show `<nil>` value didn't know how to fixed

```
php:---  $sql = "SELECT My_Data FROM page_data"; or  $sql = "SELECT My_Data FROM page_data limit 0,10";

Go :- SHOW <nil> >>>
    myquery, err := db.Prepare("SELECT pages_old FROM app_library")
    fmt.Println("Data---", myquery)
```

When I hit the below command :-
    q := "SELECT `data` FROM `page_data`"

```
rows, err := db.Query(q)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var data string // same database type
    if err := rows.Scan(&data); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Then Got the below error:

> Error: error :-- commands out of sync. Did you run multiple statements
>   at once? panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
>   dereference panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil
>   pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1
>   addr=0x0 pc=0x10bee7a]

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: How to set the limit in go language for mysql query

Answer (score 1):

[Prepare](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) used to creates a prepared statement for later queries or executions.

if you want to executes a query that returns rows use [Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)

Full Example:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

const (
    dbUser     = ""
    dbPassword = ""
    dbName     = ""
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbUser+":"+dbPassword+"@/"+dbName+"?charset=utf8")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    q := "SELECT `data` FROM `page_data`"

    rows, err := db.Query(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var data string // same database type
        if err := rows.Scan(&data); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

example it has been edited

Comment: Have try it but getting the error :-- commands out of sync. Did you run multiple statements at once?
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x10bee7a]

Comment: please, add additional details.

Comment: this command rows0, err := db.Query("SELECT app_id FROM app_library where app_id='febae795'") >> fmt.Println(rows0)  then it show me <nil> value in go language..  If I will run same command with php then it is working

Comment: use [QueryRow](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow), example [https://play.golang.org/p/2DAc6eK7Nc](https://play.golang.org/p/2DAc6eK7Nc), Please read the [Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/)

Comment: Thank, Have fixed it, There was an issues with port number